# How to download code with weird interface

Tags: bash, wget

Here is a code for Eclipse Drag and Drop

http://www.vogella.de/code/de.vogella.dnd.jface/codestartpage.html

I would like to download it, how to do it using wget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also a [git repository](https://github.com/vogella/vogella) allowing to download the complete packages as ZIP archives.

P.S.: I didn't check whether github has the same version as the webpage...

Answer (score 2):

`wget http://www.vogella.de/code/de.vogella.dnd.jface/.classpath.html` downloads the webpage with the classpath to a file on your system called `.classpath.html` (mind the . making it invisible to `ls` when not using `ls -a`).

The same aplies to all the other links. Their names are...

```
.classpath.html
.project.html
META-INF/codestartpage.html
icons/codestartpage.html
plugin.html
src/codestartpage.html
```

So all you need to do is change the `.classpath.html` in the `wget`-command to these names and you will pull each of the html files in from that website.

Comments...

The text you are after is plain text inside the HTML so this will include a bit of garbage: you will also pull in html code and anything this person put into the html file. `grep`, `sed`, `awk` are some tools that can help clean the result up.

I would recommend to copy/paste the code (the site has a plain-view and copy to clipboard) so `wget` (to me) seems to be the wrong tool.

Comment: you're right about wget. Wrong tool here.